# How to get Column Names using Linq from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to use LINQ on DataTable that's getting it's data from sql. So I have a data table with it's usual columns and rows and it appears exactly like a sql select statement. Now I need to get certain rows and columns (including column names) from this data.

I converted the datatable to something LINQ can use using AsEnumerable but I'm not sure what exactly it does. Does it convert the data into an array of objects where each row becomes an object?

I'm used to working with Javascript and it's newer arrow functions so i'd like to use Linq with lambda to keep it consistent.

I'm trying to get rows and column names where first column has a value equal to 2018

```
DataTable myTable = getData(); // populates the datatable and I've verified the data
 var linqTable = myTable.AsEnumerable().Select( x => x[0] = 2018);
```

I need to get the rows and column names. e.g like an object or array of objects.However, the code above doesn't return the data or column names but just two rows with 2018 in it.

My goal is to eventually serialize this data as json and send it to web page.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you want to serialize the results of a LINQ query?

Comment: No I don't want to serialize the results. I'll do it myself. I just want to get the data as mentioned in question.

Comment: `myTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(row => row[0] == 2018).ToList()`

Comment: ^ I'm getting Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: *but I'm not sure what exactly it does* - Well, look at the return value of `AsEnumerable`, that's what it does. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but each `DataRow` has information of its column names. BTW, use `x.Field<int>(0) == 2018`.

Comment: ^ ok. So, it seems to create an array of objects/arrays (a 2 -d array basically) which is similar to JS array of objects. Where does the .Field come from? It has itemarray within each object that contains all the values.

Comment: Stealing a bit from @RubensFarias, `myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => (int) row[0] == 2018).ToList()`

Comment: Also, How do I get the column names from this Asenumerable result?

Comment: @CaesarTex, how were you planning on using `linqTable` after it's filled?

Comment: @JamesCurran I'm going to serialize it as json using System.Web.Script.Serialization. This is an old web app using web forms and I'm kinda stuck with it..Just a  pain to work with.

Comment: @CaesarTex then you probably want to do it the way matt-dot-net just posted.

Comment: @JamesCurran That query worked but there is one issue left. how do I get the column names perhaps in a  different array? I'm trying to create a chart so I need these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Select() is projecting the objects into a new form.  You are seeing 2018 because of '=' instead of '=='.  You need to use Where()

```
 var linqTable = myTable.AsEnumerable().Where( x => x.Field<int>(0) == 2018);
```

You will still end up with a list of DataRows though.  The DataTable object isn't really what you should be using because it already provides a nice way to filter its rows:

```
myTable.Rows.Find(2018);
```

If you are trying to convert it to a list of objects you should use the Select() method something like:

```
var linqTable = myTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>(0) == 2018)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                year = x[0],
                p1 = x[1],
                p2 = x[2] // etc...
            });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Not only you answered my question but also explained the DataRow thing which I was so confused about since I got the results from Jame Curran's query. That last query with select solved my problem.

Comment: You're right about using datatables but there is lots of complex logic that's populating that datatable and I'd rather not mess with it. I thought since it looks like a table, it probably won't be that hard to get the data you want from it with code that makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

To Get the column names:

```
myTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(dc =>dc.ColumnName).ToList();
```

Comment: It Works. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following function:

```
public static DataTable CreateDataTableFromAnyCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
        }

        foreach (T entity in list)
        {
            object[] values = new object[properties.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(entity,null);
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

and pass any type of object your LINQ query returning.

```
DataTable dt = CreateDataTableFromAnyCollection(query);
```

I hope this will help you.

[Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

Comment: How is this an answer to the question being asked?

Comment: I have tried this method, it converts your LINQ query result to DataTable.

Comment: Yes, but how does that answer the question being asked? Is this an array or object with the columns names? The OP isn't clear on what he wants.

Comment: I know I can use loops and many other ways but that's not what I want. I want to keep it small and concise like you can do something like this in Javascript. Surely, C# must be able to do that easily.